# How to wait till a directory exist in Python (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, wait

In my program, After some actions a directory will appear. but for the next commands to perform I have to wait until that directory appears. I can provide directory path and the name of the directory(It's for Ubuntu). I want to wait till that directory appears.
How can I do this with Python code (in Ubuntu)?

Comment: Check if directory is created on a regular interval.

Comment: ..with `os.path.isdir('/path/to/dir')`

Comment: You can still have a race condition if the directory is created and then removed immediately. You should code defensively just in case this happens someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    if os.path.isdir("dir_path"): 
        break
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Add a `time.sleep(5)` or so in there so that you're not cooking the CPU while waiting.

Comment: Checking on regular interval is important because `while` hog downs CPU usage.

Comment: Good points here.  Also, roippi's answer of using inotify is a better solution overall

Comment: It all depends. If it's a one-shot thing that's not super time-sensitive and you don't want to bring in extra dependencies, your solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

In *nix you can take advantage of [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to give you event-driven filesystem monitoring.

The most popular python library to my (and google's) knowledge at this time is [pyinotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify/).